# Removing a Layer From Azure Maps

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-maps

I'm working with Azure maps and the weather widget, i have the weather loaded, and works great but now I want to remove it with a button, I put a click event and passed the remove function but it says layers is not a function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```js
function TriggerWeather(model, map) {

    //If there is already a layer, stop it animating.
    if (layer) {
        layer.stop();
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    //Get the current time.
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    //Get the details for the requested weather layer.
    var layerInfo = weatherLayers[model];

    //Calculate the number of timestamps.
    var numTimestamps = (layerInfo.past + layerInfo.future) / layerInfo.interval;

    var tlOptions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numTimestamps; i++) {
        //Calculate time period for an animation frame. Shift the interval by one as the olds tile will expire almost immediately.
        var time = (now - layerInfo.past) + (i + 1) * layerInfo.interval;

        //Create a tile layer option for each timestamp.
        tlOptions.push(createTileLayer(model, time));
    }

    if (layer) {
        layer.setOptions({
            tileLayerOptions: tlOptions
        });
        layer.play();
    } else {
        //Create the animation manager.
        layer = new atlas.layer.AnimatedTileLayer({
            tileLayerOptions: tlOptions,
            duration: numTimestamps * 800, //Allow one second for each frame (tile layer) in the animation.
            autoPlay: true,
            loop: true
        });

        //Add the layer to the map.
        map.layers.add(layer, 'labels');

        //Setup an interval timer to shift the layers (remove oldest, add newest) based on the update interval of the tile layer.
        timer = setInterval(intervalHandler(model), layerInfo.interval);
    }

    $('.weather').click(function() {
        if (layer) {
            // Remove the weather layer if it's already added
            map.layers.remove(layer);
        } else {
            // Add the weather layer if it's not added
            map.layers.add(layer);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided I'm not sure if there is enough information to debug it, but here is where I would start:

1. You have the code for adding the click event inside the `TriggerWeather` function. That click event doesn't appear to be removed ever, so if you call this function more than once, there would be multiple click events fired on button press, and the first one would remove the layer, and the rest would have no layer to remove and thus throw an error. Try adding a break point inside of your click event handler and see how many times it gets fired when you press the button.
2. I don't see where the `layer` object is defined/stored. Is it a globally accessible variable? It's possible that this variable isn't visible/accessible within your event handler, and thus the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply @rbrundritt, after doing a little more research i've found that im naming the layer "Labels" with "map.layers.add(layer, 'labels'), so when i call map.layers.remove i need to add 'labels' inside the remove function, now my issue is i get an error that "remove()" is not a function, i really wish Microsoft would give better documentation,

Comment: `map.layers.add(layer, 'labels')` doesn't call your layer labels, it inserts your layer under the label layers of the map. If you try and remove the "label" layer you will run into a bunch of issues. I you want to give your layer an ID/Name, that is the second parameter in the layer creation object between the data source and the options.

Comment: Your right @rbrundritt my whole method is wrong, for what my objective is- i need to create my own legend inside azure maps, when i was doing it my way i just created a div outside the map and tried to control the functionality, im sure that might be doable but i don't want to deal with it. again Thanks for your time!